# How to connect to Server socket from a different host?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I use 
`InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");`
in order to specify my host name and then I use the same number in my client code.

However, when I run client code on a different computer which is not on the same host, it does not connect to the server socket.

How can I write the client code, so that every computer can access and connect to the server code?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost. Use the IP of the server machine.

Comment: @Ironluca I wonder two things: Can a client connect to the server even if it is not on the same machine and the same network? and if need to run server code on a different machine, do I have to change each client code respectively?

Comment: @Avcı "*Can a client connect to the server even if it is not on the same machine and the same network?*" - of course it can (network hardware permitting). If that were not possible, the Internet itself would not work at all, since people's clients (web browsers, mobile apps, etc) are rarely part of the same networks of the servers they are connecting to. "*if need to run server code on a different machine, do I have to change each client code respectively?*" - no. You just need to make the server's IP address discoverable (such as via DNS), or user-entered.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you very much for your comment. I am very new at the topic. I solved the problem, but client can connect to the server only if both client and the server are connected to the same wifi. How can I change it so that client can connect to the server even if it is not connected to the same wifi?

Comment: The server needs a public IP accessible to the outside world. If the server is not *directly* connected to the Internet, it needs to be connected to a router that port-forwards its public IP traffic to the server's private IP. The client connects to its local network (WiFi, LAN, etc), then that network routes traffic to the server's network, and thus to the server. That is basic network setup, and you don't need to handle that at the client level. All the client needs to worry about is connecting to the server's public IP. If the networking is setup correctly, the rest will take care of itself

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

`InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");`

This will bind your socket to all available network interfaces.

You can use 127.0.0.1 from your host and your LAN ip from local network.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I run client code on a different computer which is not
>   on the same host, it does not connect to the server socket.

Since you're looking for a socket on `127.0.0.1`, which is the [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) interface, it is because the server is not running on the other computer. Run the server on the other computer and it should work.

> How can I write the client code, so that every computer can access and
>   connect to the server code?

The client must be aware of IP and port of the server. IP+port make up the server socket. For the connection to work in a network the server should accept connections on a network address, not just localhost. If the client connects to the server from host A, then it will connect from any host B, if B knows how to reach the server and there's nothing blocking the connection between B and the sever.
Read more about sockets in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).